# When I generated release APK with proguard I am getting errors

Tags: java, proguard

How to resolve this error?

```
Warning:com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Headers

Warning:com.ocpsoft.pretty.time.web.jsf.PrettyTimeConverter: can't find referenced class javax.faces.context.FacesContext

Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Error:Execution failed for task ':project1:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.<br>
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: Does the project build in debug configuration, without proguard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `proguard-rules.pro` file in the project:

```
-keep class com.squareup.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-keep class com.ocpsoft.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.ocpsoft.**
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for PrettyTime date library with proguard configuration. I took your last 2 lines.